Attach document to existing Docusign template document
I have a DocuSign template that includes field tags in the document. I need to attach another document to this template document. The reason for this is that the template page serves as a common page that must appear at the end of all other documents. Is it possible to attach an additional document to the existing template document using DocuSign API?
Thanks!

The recommended way of doing this is using a feature called Composite Template.
With composite templates you can have templates, documents combined in any way you want and using the eSignature API you can programmatically decide what gets sent in a given envelope.
See code example about using composite template with code examples in 8 languages.
Here is the C# code (wasn't sure which lang you need):
public static EnvelopeDefinition MakeEnvelope(
    string signerEmail,
    string signerName,
    string ccEmail,
    string ccName,
    string item,
    string quantity,
    string signerClientId,
    string templateId)
{
    // Data for this method
    // signerEmail
    // signerName
    // ccEmail
    // ccName
    // item
    // quantity
    // signerClientId -- class global

    // The envelope request object uses Composite Template to
    // include in the envelope:
    // 1. A template stored on the DocuSign service
    // 2. An additional document which is a custom HTML source document

    // Create Recipients for server template. Note that Recipients object
    // is used, not TemplateRole
    //
    // Create a signer recipient for the signer role of the server template
    Signer signer1 = new Signer
    {
        Email = signerEmail,
        Name = signerName,
        RoleName = "signer",
        RecipientId = "1",

        // Adding clientUserId transforms the template recipient
        // into an embedded recipient:
        ClientUserId = signerClientId,
    };

    // Create the cc recipient
    CarbonCopy cc1 = new CarbonCopy
    {
        Email = ccEmail,
        Name = ccName,
        RoleName = "cc",
        RecipientId = "2",
    };

    // Recipients object:
    Recipients recipientsServerTemplate = new Recipients
    {
        CarbonCopies = new List<CarbonCopy> { cc1 },
        Signers = new List<Signer> { signer1 },
    };

    // create a composite template for the Server Template
    CompositeTemplate compTemplate1 = new CompositeTemplate
    {
        CompositeTemplateId = "1",
    };
    ServerTemplate serverTemplates = new ServerTemplate
    {
        Sequence = "1",
        TemplateId = templateId,
    };

    compTemplate1.ServerTemplates = new List<ServerTemplate> { serverTemplates };

    // Add the roles via an inlineTemplate
    InlineTemplate inlineTemplate = new InlineTemplate
    {
        Sequence = "2",
        Recipients = recipientsServerTemplate,
    };
    compTemplate1.InlineTemplates = new List<InlineTemplate> { inlineTemplate };

    // The signer recipient for the added document with
    // a tab definition:
    SignHere signHere1 = new SignHere
    {
        AnchorString = "**signature_1**",
        AnchorYOffset = "10",
        AnchorUnits = "pixels",
        AnchorXOffset = "20",
    };

    Tabs signer1Tabs = new Tabs
    {
        SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere> { signHere1 },
    };

    // Signer definition for the added document
    Signer signer1AddedDoc = new Signer
    {
        Email = signerEmail,
        Name = signerName,
        ClientUserId = signerClientId,
        RoleName = "signer",
        RecipientId = "1",
        Tabs = signer1Tabs,
    };

    // Recipients object for the added document:
    Recipients recipientsAddedDoc = new Recipients
    {
        CarbonCopies = new List<CarbonCopy> { cc1 },
        Signers = new List<Signer> { signer1AddedDoc },
    };

    // create the HTML document
    Document doc1 = new Document();

    string doc1B64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Document1(signerEmail, signerName, ccEmail, ccName, item, quantity));
    doc1.DocumentBase64 = doc1B64;
    doc1.Name = "Appendix 1--Sales order"; // can be different from actual file name
    doc1.FileExtension = "html";
    doc1.DocumentId = "1";

    // create a composite template for the added document
    CompositeTemplate compTemplate2 = new CompositeTemplate
    {
        CompositeTemplateId = "2",
    };

    // Add the recipients via an inlineTemplate
    InlineTemplate inlineTemplate2 = new InlineTemplate
    {
        Sequence = "1",
        Recipients = recipientsAddedDoc,
    };
    compTemplate2.InlineTemplates = new List<InlineTemplate> { inlineTemplate2 };
    compTemplate2.Document = doc1;

    EnvelopeDefinition env = new EnvelopeDefinition
    {
        Status = "sent",
        CompositeTemplates = new List<CompositeTemplate> { compTemplate1, compTemplate2 },
    };

    return env;
}

public static byte[] Document1(
    string signerEmail,
    string signerName,
    string ccEmail,
    string ccName,
    string item,
    string quantity)
{
    // Data for this method
    // signerEmail
    // signerName
    // ccEmail
    // ccName
    // item
    // quantity
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(" <!DOCTYPE html>\n" +
            "    <html>\n" +
            "        <head>\n" +
            "          <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">\n" +
            "        </head>\n" +
            "        <body style=\"font-family:sans-serif;margin-left:2em;\">\n" +
            "        <h1 style=\"font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, sans-serif;\n" +
            "            color: darkblue;margin-bottom: 0;\">World Wide Corp</h1>\n" +
            "        <h2 style=\"font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, sans-serif;\n" +
            "          margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 3.5em;font-size: 1em;\n" +
            "          color: darkblue;\">Order Processing Division</h2>\n" +
            "        <h4>Ordered by " + signerName + "</h4>\n" +
            "        <p style=\"margin-top:0em; margin-bottom:0em;\">Email: " + signerEmail + "</p>\n" +
            "        <p style=\"margin-top:0em; margin-bottom:0em;\">Copy to: " + ccName + "," + ccEmail + "</p>\n" +
            "        <p style=\"margin-top:3em; margin-bottom:0em;\">Item: <b>" + item + "</b>, quantity: <b>" + quantity + "</b> at market price.</p>\n" +
            "        <p style=\"margin-top:3em;\">\n" +
            "  Candy bonbon pastry jujubes lollipop wafer biscuit biscuit. Topping brownie sesame snaps sweet roll pie. Croissant danish biscuit soufflé caramels jujubes jelly. Dragée danish caramels lemon drops dragée. Gummi bears cupcake biscuit tiramisu sugar plum pastry. Dragée gummies applicake pudding liquorice. Donut jujubes oat cake jelly-o. Dessert bear claw chocolate cake gummies lollipop sugar plum ice cream gummies cheesecake.\n" +
            "        </p>\n" +
            "        <!-- Note the anchor tag for the signature field is in white. -->\n" +
            "        <h3 style=\"margin-top:3em;\">Agreed: <span style=\"color:white;\">**signature_1**/</span></h3>\n" +
            "        </body>\n" +
            "    </html>");
}


Thanks for suggesting the above method! Instead of attaching document, we adopted a different approach where tags are added to the document using API.
